# Trying desperately to switch from Windows XP to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, screen-corruption

My son has a laptop that I installed Ubuntu on as dual boot. The other OS is Windows XP, that runs perfectly and has for some time now. I had a hard drive, installed it, installed Windows XP (SP2) on it, then put in the SAME Ubuntu disk I used on my son's computer, and it went through the ENTIRE installation/setup process.

Then when I went to reboot the computer, I was expecting to have to select which operating system, but it goes straight into trying to boot up on Ubuntu, it goes through the initial splash screen, displaying information about my system, then the screen goes black and the cursor is blinking in the top left-hand corner of the screen, then goes off and comes back on screen one or two lines further down, but nothing other than the cursor is on the screen, and that is where it stays. It will not do anything else. I can press Ctrl+Alt+Del, and it will reboot or I can manually power down, but it comes back to the same point. This is home built computer that I have been using for a long time. I just want to get away from Microsoft, other than dual boot for iTunes.

My hardware specs:
 ⠀AMD 64 processor 1.8GHz
 ⠀Asus motherboard
 ⠀Asus video card in AGP slot
 ⠀Sound card
 ⠀2 or 3 GB RAM

I love Ubuntu, is there anything to be done?

Comment: The first step would be to login to a text-only console. Press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter the console. You will be prompted to enter your username and then press Enter. You will be prompted to enter your login password and then press Enter. Now you are logged in. Run the command `lspci -nn | grep VGA` to get the model of your AGP graphics card. You're getting the black screen because you're missing the AGP card's driver, I think. Edit your answer and add the results of running the command to it. This information will help to find out how to install the missing driver.

Comment: One more thing - how to exit from the console. You can run the command `sudo shutdown -h now` to shutdown or `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Problem with GRUB (The programm that lets you select, which OS to start (bootloader)). You can try to reinstall Ubuntu, this should install GRUB back to your disc and it should work again. Maybe you also have to switch the device to install the bootloader on during setup. There are also some guides on how to repair GRUB, but easiest way for you probably is to reinstall Ubuntu.